# Find the number of $6 \times 7$ matrices with entries $[0,1]$ such that their row and column sums are odd.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, algebra-precalculus, permutations, permutation-cycles

My attempt is quite handwaivy. But I think this has something to do with permutation matrices. I am absolutely new to this topic. can anyone throw any light on this solution?
I know there are $2^{n\times m}$ binary matrices of size $n\times m$, and $n!m!$ possible permutations, but somehow I fail to get an intuition on what this implies for the equivalence classes.

Comment: So the entry could be 1/2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the row sums are all odd, then the total number of $1$s is the sum of these $6$ odd numbers, hence even. If the column sums are all odd, then the total number of $1$s is the sum of these $7$ odd numbers, hence odd. A contradiction; hence the number of such matrices is $0$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe If the column sums are odd, then the sum of sums is odd because there are $7$ columns.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe To reach a contradiction. Have you read my answer?